# Editing display of submission results

Tags: 8, webforms

I'm working on a Drupal 8 site, and I'd like to adjust how the results (/admin/structure/webform/manage/*form-name*/submission/*ID*/edit) display – the client doesn't want to see all of the fields and submission-related information (UUID, URI, etc.), and wants to see all of the form submission fields filled out here as well.

I see that there's an option for [submission views](https://www.drupal.org/node/2994274), but I don't see a similar option that applies to the Edit tab. I also see there's a [Webform Views Integration module](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_views), but that looks more like what I'd want if I wanted to put a view within a form.

Is there configuration I'm not seeing to adjust the submission edit screen, or a better method of reviewing submission details on a page whose display I can customize?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there configuration I'm not seeing to adjust the submission edit screen

No, there is no config screen to customize this "edit" screen.

> the client doesn't want to see all of the fields and
>   submission-related information (UUID, URI, etc.)

You can use [hook_form_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Form%21form.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/8.2.x) in a custom module and remove the submission information section.

> and wants to see all of the form submission fields filled out here as
>   well.

They should be already be filled out, unless the user left them empty. Make these fields required if they should be filled out.

> I also see there's a [Webform Views Integration module](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_views), but that
>   looks more like what I'd want if I wanted to put a view within a form.

In correct, this allows you to display the webform results in a View. This is exactly what you need, well if you want to make an alternate page that has that "edit" info.

Also, you could alter the Webform's edit route so it uses your Webform View instead, but you would lose the edit ability tho. Since the View just displays what was entered and is not a form.